# Entity Framework Code First vs DB First: Trap Relationship Constraint Problems

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Two questions:

1. Does Entity Framework (Code First) trap "Relationship Constraint" problems (such as foreign key constraint violation) **before it hits database** i.e. in the application.
2. As far as I know, Entity Framework (DB First) does not trap "Relationship Constraint" problems in the application space; it waits until SaveChanges method fails due to constraint violation error(s) get raised from database. Is there any way to force it check the relationships **automatically**?

Answer (score 0):

1. Nope.
2. Nope.

Sorry.

You really don't want that - another user might insert data into the DB making a foreign key reference suddenly valid.

Comment: Not really, I thought I was pretty clear. You don't want EF to verify a relationship constraint before hitting the DB - it should always check the DB to make sure your data is valid, because someone else might have modified some data in your DB making your save invalid or even suddenly valid. It can't just 'know' that your data is ok.

Comment: Got it. thanks. Probably this can just be another interview question. :) lets see how many candidates i can confuse now.

Comment: @LachlanB With respect, I should say your statement contradicts with what Julie Lerman says in "Programming Entity Framework: DBContext" book page 178: "SaveChanges will detect relationship constraint problems even if they are not defined in a way that ValidateEntity will trap them."

Comment: @LachlanB So far, I encountered many cases when a logical argument contradicts with what Microsoft does (disagreemnt between developers and Microsoft !). So what seems logical is not necessarily implemented.

Comment: @Alireza don't be so quick to blame microsoft, I have found that most of the time they have a good reason for doing whatever they do.

Comment: @LachlanB Yes, yes I ment exactly as what you said. I ment what seems logical to us may not be the best solution because Microsoft is the Oracle in its products!